# Get data audit log report for users(Power bi pro) using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powerbi, powerquery, sharepoint-online

We have written a PowerShell script for extracting audit log data for Power BI Pro users. Previously it was working fine, from one month onwards, we are getting access dined error while running script. We are using correct credentials and also tried a non-MFA account, the same issue coming. Error message as below:

> New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message: Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. At E:\location\Folder\Auditreport.ps1:66 char:12

> $Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Conne ...
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed Import-PSSession : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again. At E:\location\Folder\Auditreport.ps1:70 char:18
> Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber

**Powershell Script**

```
cls
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$PSScriptRoot\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$PSScriptRoot\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")

# getting data from config file
$Data = [Xml] (Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Config.xml)

$PowerBIUser=$Data.data.record |where {$_.key -eq "PowerBIUser"} | select value
$PowerBIUser=$PowerBIUser.value

$SecurePasswordpath=$Data.data.record |where {$_.key -eq "Securepasswordpath"} | select value
$SecurePasswordpath=$PSScriptRoot+"\"+$SecurePasswordpath.value

$AppId=$Data.data.record |where {$_.key -eq "AppId"} | select value
$AppId=$AppId.value

$AppSecret=$Data.data.record |where {$_.key -eq "AppSecret"} | select value
$AppSecret=$AppSecret.value

$SourceUrl=$Data.data.record |where {$_.key -eq "SourceUrl"} | select value
$SourceUrl=$SourceUrl.value

$SourceListProUsers=$Data.data.record |where {$_.key -eq "SourceListProUsers"} | select value
$SourceListProUsers=$SourceListProUsers.value

$securePassword = Get-Content $SecurePasswordpath | ConvertTo-SecureString
$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($PowerBIUser, $securePassword)

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SourceUrl -ClientId $AppId -ClientSecret $AppSecret

$startDate=(get-date).AddDays(-90)
$endDate=(get-date)
$scriptStart=(get-date)

#Establish session to exchange online and import unified audit log commandlets required for security and compliance audit log search
$Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

#Import-PSSession -Session $Session | Out-Null

Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber

$ItemsPBIProUsers = Get-PnPListItem -List PBIProUsers
       
If($ItemsPBIProUsers) {
$ItemsPBIProUsers | ForEach { 
                               
$UserEmail=$_['UserPrincipalName'];
   #write-host  $UserEmail
             
     $sessionName = (get-date -Format 'u')+'pbiauditlog'
# Reset user audit accumulator
$aggregateResults = @()
$i = 0 # Loop counter
Do { 

#$currentResults = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $enddate -SessionId $sessionName -SessionCommand ReturnLargeSet -ResultSize 1000 -RecordType PowerBI
#$UserEmail="_PowerBiGate@test.com";
$currentResults = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -UserIds $UserEmail -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $enddate -SessionId $sessionName -SessionCommand ReturnLargeSet -ResultSize 1000 -RecordType PowerBI

Write-Host( $UserEmail + "-" +  $currentResults.Count);

    if ($currentResults.Count -gt 0) {

#Write-Host( $UserEmail + "-" +  $currentResults.Count);
        #Write-Host ("  Finished {3} search #{1}, {2} records: {0} min" -f [math]::Round((New-TimeSpan -Start $scriptStart).TotalMinutes,4), $i, $currentResults.Count, $user.UserPrincipalName )
        # Accumulate the data
        $aggregateResults += $currentResults
        # No need to do another query if the # recs returned <1k - should save around 5-10 sec per user
        if ($currentResults.Count -lt 1000) {
            $currentResults = @()
        } else {
            $i++
        }
    }
} Until ($currentResults.Count -eq 0) # --- End of Session Search Loop --- #

            try {
          $aggregateResults=  $aggregateResults | Sort CreationDate -Descending
            if ($aggregateResults.Count -gt 0)
                    {
                        $CreationDate=$aggregateResults[0].CreationDate.Date
                        $_['LastActivityDate'] = $CreationDate
                        $_.SystemUpdate()
                        Invoke-PnPQuery
                    }
                    }
            catch {
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            write-host $ErrorMessage
        }
   }
}

<#
$data=@()
foreach ($auditlogitem in $aggregateResults) {
    $datum = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
    $d=convertfrom-json $auditlogitem.AuditData
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Id –Value $d.Id
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name CreationTime –Value $auditlogitem.CreationDate
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name CreationTimeUTC –Value $d.CreationTime
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name RecordType –Value $d.RecordType
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Operation –Value $d.Operation
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name OrganizationId –Value $d.OrganizationId
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserType –Value $d.UserType
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserKey –Value $d.UserKey
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Workload –Value $d.Workload
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserId –Value $d.UserId
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ClientIP –Value $d.ClientIP
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name UserAgent –Value $d.UserAgent
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Activity –Value $d.Activity
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ItemName –Value $d.ItemName
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name WorkSpaceName –Value $d.WorkSpaceName
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DashboardName –Value $d.DashboardName
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DatasetName –Value $d.DatasetName
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ReportName –Value $d.ReportName
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name WorkspaceId –Value $d.WorkspaceId
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ObjectId –Value $d.ObjectId
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DashboardId –Value $d.DashboardId
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name DatasetId –Value $d.DatasetId
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ReportId –Value $d.ReportId
    $datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name OrgAppPermission –Value $d.OrgAppPermission

    #option to include the below JSON column however for large amounts of data it may be difficult for PBI to parse
    #$datum | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Datasets –Value (ConvertTo-Json $d.Datasets)

    #below is a poorly constructed PowerShell statemnt to grab one of the entries and place in the DatasetName if any exist
    foreach ($dataset in $d.datasets) {
        $datum.DatasetName = $dataset.DatasetName
        $datum.DatasetId = $dataset.DatasetId
    }
    $data+=$datum
}

$datestring = $startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$fileName = ("c:\PBIAuditLogs\" + $datestring + ".csv")
Write-Host (" writing to file {0}" -f $fileName)
$data | Export-csv $fileName

#>

Remove-PSSession -Id $Session.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

There are generally only [3 reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/access-denied-connect-powershell) for an access denied response:

> - You enter an incorrect user name or password.
> - You try to sign in to the service by using an account that doesn't have access to Exchange Online.
> - You have security defaults enabled in your tenant.

The *most* likely reason is that the account is locked out or you're using the wrong password, so double-check that `Get-Content $SecurePasswordpath` returns a usable password for that account.

---

You may also have had `BasicAuth` [disabled](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-february-2021-update/ba-p/2111904) for [your organization](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-july-update/ba-p/1530163), though it shouldn't happen automatically for another month or so. You can check with `Get-AuthenticationPolicy` if it was done through a policy, though if your org is using security defaults you might have nothing there.

I would recommend updating your script to use the [ExchangeOnline V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) module either way rather than using `New-PSSession` to connect.